# Building ranges using python set-builder notation

Tags: list, set, python

Hey, I am trying to build a set of ranges in python like so:

Given `(0.1, 0.2, 0.7)`

I want to build `[(0, 0.1), (0.1, 0.3), (0.3, 1)]`

While this could be achieved easily through a regular for-loop, as a learning exercise I wanted to see if this could be achieved via a set-builder expression.

My first thought was to do `[(i, i+t) for i = 0, i+=t, t in (0.1, 0.2, 0.7)]`, however that is not valid syntax, I tried a few other expressions, however I noticed that it is not possible to assign values to variables inside the expression. Looking for information, it seems that in list-builder expressions you can iterate through various other iterable objects at the same time, but not keep a state.

So I want to know if it is at all possible to do something like this in a "pythonic" way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that just looping is a way more Pythonic. Write a generator function:

```
def build_ranges(steps):
    val = 0
    for step in steps:
        yield val, val + step
        val += step
```

Then:

```
>>> input = (0.1, 0.2, 0.7)
>>> list(build_ranges(input))
[(0, 0.10000000000000001), (0.10000000000000001, 0.30000000000000004), (0.30000000000000004, 1.0)]
```

Comment: I did not know about the yield keyword, I ended up needing to do this more often, so a function was ultimately the way to go

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is:

```
a = (0.1, 0.2, 0.7)
l = [(sum(a[:ii]), sum(a[:ii+1])) for ii, v in enumerate(a)]
```

Yet being pythonic does not mean being the most concise, or using comprehensions at any place possible - if a simple loop is more readable, go for it (if there are no other factors hinting to a list comprehension, for example).